# Retrieve the initial commit from where a new branch was split off with the GitHub API

Tags: javascript, github-actions, github-api

I want to find the commit SHA from where a new branch was created. I want to know this for a GitHub JavaScript action, which is run in the GitHub CI. The runner is ran when a new push to a branch is made. At that point it is not known from which branch this pushed-to branch is split from.

```
         o---o---o---B
        /
---o---1---o---o---o---A
```

Let's say we have a branch B and a main branch A. I want to find the initial commit from where the B branch split off. In the graphic this commit is market as 1. The GitHub CLI has a command called git merge-base which does something similar. I am wondering if this kind if thing is possible with the GitHub API.

I have looked through the GitHub API Docs (https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28) and couldn't figure out a method for how to approach this. There does not seem to be a straight equivalent to git merge-base, but there might be a way to still get the same results in a slightly roundabout way. Hopefully someone can help me out on this front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the most recent common ancestor of two branches using GitHub REST API, you should [compare two commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#compare-two-commits).

Specify the branches you want to compare in the `basehead` parameter like this : `A...B`.

In the response, read the `merge_base_commit` key. It is the common ancestor of your branches. Then read its `sha` key.